# Change hostname of Linux machine

Tags: linux, dns

I have a host "india.niksula.hut.fi". I want to change it to "test.india.niksula.hut.fi". I ran the command:

```
sudo hostname test.india.niksula.hut.fi
```

I also modified the /etc/hostname file to have "test.india" instead of "india", which was previously the case. When I ran the command:

```
hostname --fqdn
```

I get "test.india.niksula.hut.fi". Now, when I am trying to ping that name from another machine, it gives:

```
ping: unknown host test.india.niksula.hut.fi
```

SSH also gives the same result. I need to be able to access the name "test.india.niksula.hut.fi". Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is off-topic here on SO, but I'll tell you the reason anyway: You only change the hostname *locally*, you haven't changed and DNS that the rest of the world uses to map host-names to IP-addresses.

Comment: Yes, I saw that just now, pinging the host locally by that name works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How should the other machine know about the host name at all? Have you a DNS-service running where you store your host mames with the corresponding IP addresses?

So you either run a DNS service or store the host-names with the proper IP addresses in your `/ets/hosts` on all your machines.